# mysql_query. Select from same column, but from two different years

Tags: mysql, sql, select, graph

I have a database with "date" and "temperature readings". I use this values to make a graph that shows temperature readings trought the whole year.

At the moment I have all the readings from 2016 in one graph, but I like to make two graphs. One from 2015 and one from 2016.

Is it posible to select "out_temp", AS "temp_2015" and "out temp" AS "temp_2016"?

to add my data to google chart, I need the following columns, "date" , "temp_2015" and "temp_2016".

Here is what I have:

```
$result = mysql_query
                      ("
                      SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%u.%y') AS Time1    ,    out_temp AS out_temp 
                      FROM $table 
                      where YEAR(date)=2016;
                      ");
```

Thank you for your help

Ørjan

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%u.%y') AS Time1,    
case when YEAR(date) = 2015 then  out_temp else 0 end as temp_2015,
case when YEAR(date) = 2016 then  out_temp else 0 end as temp_2016
FROM $table
```

this will work if you have 1 reading for each year. 
I think you may have more than one reading so you can use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%u.%y') AS Time1,    
avg(case when YEAR(date) = 2015 then  out_temp else 0 end) as temp_2015,
avg(case when YEAR(date) = 2016 then  out_temp else 0 end) as temp_2016
FROM $table
group by DATE_FORMAT(date, '%u.%y')
```

Comment: I have tried to do as you say, but I get no result? no reading

Comment: can you show a bit of your input table - and what type exactly is `date` ?

Comment: Hi, "date" is a datetime column. 2015-02-02 10:34:42

Comment: try again - I had a syntax error with the year(date) for some reason

Comment: hi. i have manage to program your example. I now have two sets of temperature readings. One from 2015 and one from 2016. The problem is that the time axes is stil going all the way from 2015 to 2016. I want the time axes to go one year, and the two graps going on top of each other.

Comment: but that depends on your plotting methods which have nothing to do with the above code

Comment: Hi This is how i make the plot matrix    $num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) 
{$time=mysql_result($result,$i,"Time1");
$temp_2016=mysql_result($result,$i,"temp_2016");
echo "['";
echo "$time";
echo "',";
echo "$temp_2016";
echo "]";
if ($i < ($num - 1)){ echo ","; }  $i++;

Comment: hi, i got it to work. Thanks for all your help. http://temperatur.co.nf/year.php and http://temperatur.co.nf/readings.php

Answer (score 0):

you can write two same queries resulting in two result arrays. after that you can merge it into a single array and plotting graph on date basis condition... as you know better how you will plot graph , change your data accordingly..

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm new to to this and dont undertand how to write what you are describing.

Comment: Suppose you get a result array 2015: $temp15 = array(0=>array(0=>10,1=>42)); in showing date and degreess, same you got another array writing the same query for 2016 year matching . then you merge both arrays using array_merge() and you can plot your chart.. you just need to figure out how to arrange your arrays data to plot that chart..  .. query you will write will be the same as you have written already fetching a new result based on new year........so far i get from your question.....

Comment: hi. the problem i have is that the time axes goes from 2015 to 2016. i manage to split the temerature readings in years. but when i plot them, the 2015 grap is first, then the 2016 grap continues. I like the graps to lay on top of each other so that i can compare them. Is it posible to just fecth the week number or something to exlude the year? so that the two readings can have similar time axes?

Comment: hi, i got it to work. Thanks for all your help. http://temperatur.co.nf/year.php and http://temperatur.co.nf/readings.php